# How to validate a WTF MultiCheckboxField to see if at least one box is checked?

Tags: python, validation, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a simple MultiCheckboxField() as;

```py
class MultiCheckboxField(SelectMultipleField):
    widget = widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False)
    option_widget = widgets.CheckboxInput()
```

And I used that class as the following;

```py
visible_for_perms = MultiCheckboxField(label=lazy_gettext("Visible for Permissions"),
                               coerce=str,
                               choices=APPLICATION_PERMISSIONS,
                               validators=[])
```

There are 15 entries in choices list. What I would like to achieve is to check if at least one of the 15 choices is selected. When there is no checked box, the form cannot be submitted. I could not find any helpful solution for such validation. I want to do this on the python code without using JQuery.

I have tried to validate this field by input_required() but it requires all the boxes to be checked.